Access different widgets and functions in tkinter from different classes
I have an application that transforms coordinates from one system to another. The source and the target frames use many similar functions like the ones executed when a combobox change.
How to create thes functions once and use them in both frames
Here is an example of these function that is executed when combobox geographic format is modified in the source system. I wrote the same one for the target system
 def modified_combo_gf_src(choice):
        chaine = chaine2 = chaine3 = ''
        if choice == "deg":
            chaine = "Latitude φ en °"
            chaine2 = "Longitude λ en °"
        if choice == "gon":
            chaine = "Latitude φ en gon"
            chaine2 = "Longitude λ en gon"
        if choice == "rad":
            chaine = "Latitude φ en rad"
            chaine2 = "Longitude λ en rad"
        if choice == "dms":
            chaine = "Latitude  φ en ° ' \""
            chaine2 = "Longitude λ en ° ' \""
        if choice == "pdms":
            chaine = "Latitude φ en pdms"
            chaine2 = "Longitude λ en pdms"
        lbl_coord_x_src.configure(text=chaine)
        lbl_coord_y_src.configure(text=chaine2)


I am expecting to have one function to deal with the equivalent widgets in the source and target tabs.

You can either return the texts as tuple of strings and add in each frame code to set the texts in the appropriate widgets or you call the function with the widgets as additional parameters.

it could be simpler to use f-string f"Latitude φ en {target}" and assing target = "°" - and later you could set text=f"Latitude φ en {target}" text=f"Longitude λ en {target}" - so it need only one variable target instead of two variables chaine and chaine2. And later you could even use dictionary to convert target val = {"deg": "°", ...} and target = val.get(choice)

If you need to use with different Labels then send them as arguments
def modified_combo_gf_src(choice, label_x, label_y):

    # ... code ...

    label_x.configure(text=chaine)
    label_y.configure(text=chaine2)

And if you need to use conversion with different elements then maybe move conversion to separate function
def convert(choice):

    # ... code ...
 
    return chaine, chaine2


def modified_combo_gf_src(choice, label_x, label_y):

    tex1, text2 = convert(choice)

    label_x.configure(text=text1)
    label_y.configure(text=text2)

def other_function(choice...):

    tex1, text2 = convert(choice)

    # ... other code ... e.g. write in file


BTW: You could use f-string to generate f"Latitude φ en {target}"
def modified_combo_gf_src(choice, label_x, label_y):

    if choice == "deg":
        target = "°"
    elif choice == "gon":
        target = "gon"
    elif choice == "rad":
        target = "rad"
    elif choice == "dms":
        target = "° ' \""
    elif choice == "pdms":
        target = "pdms"
    else:
        target = None
        
    if target:            
        label_x.configure(text=f"Latitude φ en {target}")
        label_y.configure(text=f"Longitude λ en {target}")
    else:
        print(f"ERROR: wrong choice {choice}")

And you could reduce if/elif using dictionary
def modified_combo_gf_src(choice, label_x, label_y):
        
    val = {
        "deg": "°", 
        "gon": "gon", 
        "rad": "rad", 
        "dms": "° ' \"", 
        "pdms": "pdms"
    }

    target = val.get(choice)
        
    if target:            
        label_x.configure(text=f"Latitude φ en {target}")
        label_y.configure(text=f"Longitude λ en {target}")
    else:
        print(f"ERROR: wrong choice {choice}")

Less readable - in one line target = {...}.get(choice)
target = {"deg": "°", "gon": "gon", "rad": "rad", "dms": "° ' \"", "pdms": "pdms"}.get(choice)


Thanks for your suggestion @furas. But when trying to call this function for the other frame, I always get an error. Indeed, I have two similar frames for source and target. The source is used to get the coordinates and the target to display the computation result but they exactly have the same widgets (labels, entries, combos). How to instanciate the target from the source properly?

I have no idea what error you get and I have no idea if you use it correctly. if you have error then show it in question - it will be more readable - and show code which you used.

if two widgets are in the same frame (or other widget) then they have the same parent - in tkinter it is .master. In other GUIs (or if you would use Class) you could use source.master.target but in tkinter it would need to get .master.childrenand search target object on list (checking type of widget and its namestr(widget)`)
